# Восстановление данных со старой системы

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint

У меня стоял linux mint, я переустановил его на ubuntu, и затёр файловую систему.

Нужно возобновить папку со старой linux mint, делал анализ testdisc'ом, но он находит только мою систему и файлы, которые были удалени на ubuntu, что сейчас стоит...

Старую систему не находит.

Есть шанс восстановить?

Answer (score 5):

> Есть шанс восстановить?

коротко: нет.

длинно: при некоторой доли везения и знании уникальных отрывков текста, хранившегося в этих файлах, вы, вероятно, сможете (после полного побайтового сканирования) найти места на диске, где эти отрывки текста встречаются.

но эти «находки», с огромной долей вероятности, абсолютно никак не помогут восстановить даже файлы (только фрагменты этих файлов). а уж про каталоги вообще, по-моему, речи быть не может.